# pushing a image to Openshift with a Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I do have images in my registry but now I want to validate my docker builds with a Jenkins file and later do blue green deployments. However I am getting the following error:

```
error: The server uses a certificate signed by unknown authority. You 
may need to use the --certificate-authority flag to provide the path to 
a certificate file for the certificate authority, or --insecure-skip-
tls-verify to bypass the certificate check and use insecure 
connections.
```

Jenkins file:

```
node {

    stage('Checkout source control') {
      checkout scm
    }

    stage('connect') {
       sh "oc login <my URL> --token=<my token>"
    }

    stage('build api container') {
        sh "oc new-build --name=api --binary=true"
        sh "oc start-build api --from-dir=docker/api --follow"
    }

}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have thought of ways but this one seems to fit my needs the best.

I am also not using minishift, I am just wanting to pull multiple repositories and check the build.

When I remove the login I get the following error:

```
[workspace] Running shell script

+ oc new-build --name=api --binary=true

Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable

script returned exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each [sh](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script) call has its own "context". Your connection is lost already in the second `sh`. Try multiline call:

```groovy
   sh("""
       oc login <my URL> --token=<my token>
       oc new-build --name=api --binary=true
       oc start-build api --from-dir=docker/api --follow
   """)
```

To avoid errors with certificates add `--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true` or `--certificate-authority` with path to `ca.crt` to login command. I think it's better to use `--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true` for a simpler understanding and maintainability of your pipeline.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know of a better way to login? It its rather messy to push my token to bitbucket but it does login now. However I now get 

`Removing intermediate container 0efdafc1f0e3`

`Step 4 : COPY api.war´ ´$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/api.war`

`error: build error: lstat api.war: no such file or directory`. But it is in the Dockerfile directory api. The api directory has `setenv.sh`, `api.war` and a `Dockerfile`. It works fine just using the command in the terminal but not while in the jenkins file.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you missed some settings or dependencies so there's an error. On which `node` do you start your pipeline? 
Also you can try this [plugin](https://blog.openshift.com/using-openshift-pipeline-plugin-external-jenkins/) will help. It  will add `Openshift` pipeline steps.

Comment: I am about to accept the answer but I figured out the issue. In the directory I have the war file there but in my `.gitignore` file I have `.war` so naturally it cannot find it in bitbucket. The images are in Openshift but now I am just looking at a brick wall wondering how to fix this.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not help here, not much worked with `Openshift`.If you solve this issue, please describe it for other users.